# MySQL value of a parameter that reruns every entry

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to set value of a parameter such that in where clause it always results true?

As example consider a query:

```
SELECT name FROM student WHERE class=@parameter;
```

Now my question is "is it possible to set a value of parameter such that this query reruns name of every student".

Comment: Simply: no, not without changing the rest of the query.

Comment: One way I can think of is by Injecting `1=1`. Always append this string to the end of your parameter `@parameter = 'class name' or 1=1`

Answer (score 1):

The typical method is:

```
SELECT name
FROM student
WHERE (class = @parameter OR @parameter IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want every entry you can try

```
SELECT name FROM student WHERE 1=1
```

For a single field:

```
SELECT name FROM student WHERE class like '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this, try this:

```
SELECT name FROM student WHERE class=class;
```

but I guess @parameter binding will cause this to be:

```
SELECT name FROM student WHERE class='class';
```

So, if you don't change the @parameter binding, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `SELECT name FROM student` without where.